# Views are not loaded when injected $location into main controller

Tags: angularjs

Below is my index.html file :

```
<body ng-controller="MyController" ng-cloak>
    <div ng-if="isAuthenticated">
        <div ng-include="'shared/header/client.header.view.html'"></div>
        <div ng-view></div>
        <div ng-include="'shared/footer/client.footer.view.html'"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="alert alert-{{alert.type}} animated main-alert" ng-class="{'flipInY': alert.show, 'flipOutY': !alert.show, 'alert-hidden': !alert.hasBeenShown}">
        <strong>{{alert.title}}</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{alert.message}}
        <br/>
        <center>
            <button data-dismiss="alert">Ok</button>
        </center>
    </div>
</body>
```

Route configuration:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when("/dashboard", {
            templateUrl: "components/dashboard/client.dashboard.view.html",
        }).when("/sales", {
            templateUrl: "components/dashboard/client.sales.view.html",
            controller: "SalesController"
        }).when("/settings", {
            templateUrl: "shared/common_components/client.proxyuser.view.html"
        }).otherwise("/dashboard");
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = {};
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {};
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.put = {};
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.patch = {};
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = {};
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
    });
```

Controller :

```
var MyController= function ($scope, $http, authtoken, alert, buyer, API_URL) { 
       //code
        }
    app.controller("MyController", MyController);
```

With the above code, all my views will be rendered and displayed properly. But when i am injecting $location into buyer controller, only header and footer html's are included, but no views are loaded.

```
var MyController= function ($scope, $location, $http, authtoken, alert, buyer, API_URL) {

        //With this $location injection, no views are loaded.
        }
```

Their are no console log errors displayed.

Am i making any mistake by adding ng-view tag inside the controller?.

Comment: Do you do somewhere a `MyController.$inject = [..]` ?

Comment: `BuyerController != MyController` so confusing what you are really doing.

Comment: @charlietfl : Sorry for that. I have edited the post now.

Comment: @devqon : I am new to angular js, I don't know how to use $inject. Will explore on $inject and let you know the results. Thanks.

Comment: @devqon: Hey i tried that, But still the issue is same, when $location is injected views are not getting loaded. Beside from Angular JS Docs i came to know that $inject is mainly used for minifiers to match the dependencies. My code is not minified yet. So i don't think it will be a problem for now. Anyway thanks.